# Add product manual search

Tags: magento-2.1, database, custom-attributes, cms-pages, download-link

I need to add an option for searching product manuals. I have some pdf files as manuals which stored in folder named as it's manufacturer. Ex: manufacturer is ABC and manuals are abc-prmanu1.pdf, abc-prmanu2.pdf etc..

I have separate `CMS` page,**(Search Page)** that has a `select/dropdown` which should have the manufacturer names. upon selecting manufacturer, there is a button, on-click it should display every manual pdf files in another page.**(View Page)**, which lists all available product manuals for selected manufacturer and have download links for each individual pdf file.

How can I accomplish this?

How can I store manufacturer names, manual names, ids and other data?(Do I need to use database or can I use some kind of attribute option?)

Please help me